# aop eventinterceptionaspect postsharp

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, aop, postsharp

What would be the best practice to implement save/restore layout funcionality for every DeveloperExpress XtraGrid control in my application. I use a lot of Grid visual elements on every winform in my application (GridControl, LookUpEdit, SearchLookUpEdit...) and currently I'm poluting every winform with load/unload events that call save/restore functionality for each Grid element on that form manually. I already have an extension method that makes saving/restoring Grids a matter of one function call now I want to have one centralized class where I would take care for saving/restoring each Grid type in my application.

I'm new to aop but could something like this be done with tools like postsharp and a global eventinterceptionaspect where load/unload events would be applied to each Grid type that gets initialised in my assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can intercept events using PostSharp. You can check out the following article to get a walk-through http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/PostSharp-Principals-Day-11-e28093-Interception-e28093-Part-3.aspx

You can build an aspect that just calls out to your extension methods when the event is fired. Aspects can be applied globally to save you some work using multicasting http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/Day-2-Applying-Aspects-with-Multicasting-Part-1.aspx http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/Day-3-Applying-Aspects-with-Multicasting-Part-2.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the links. I read the blog posts, but if I understand you have to annotate events with the [EventAspect]. So does that mean you can intercept only events from your source code... in my case I want to intercept "XtraGrid.Load" event. Would it be better in my case to write an OnMethodBoundary aspect and intercept the OnLoad method that probably invokes the Load event?

Comment: Check out http://www.sharpcrafters.com/downloads/samples/2.1/ModifyThirdAssembly.zip I havent done this yet, but it's possible. I would recommend you intercept your own code, but give that a try

Comment: @Jernej Gorički For a walk-through please see http://programmersunlimited.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/applying-aspects-to-3rd-party-assemblies-using-postsharp/

Comment: Ok, after playing arround with postsharp samples I realised that intercepting methods from third party samples would not be a an efficient way to solve my problem... I really should be intercepting my own code as you suggested, but I don't see anymore that aop would be the correct solution for my problem.

Comment: It isn't always the right choice, at least you saw that now instead of after you've already invested dev time.